# Cannot access Spark dataframe methods

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

In Zeppelin I am using a dataframe created in another paragraph. I display the type of my df variable and get:

```
res35: String = DataFrame
```

suggesting it is a dataframe. But when I try and use select on the df variable I get an error:

```
<console>:62: error: value select is not a member of Object
```

Do I have to convert Object to Dataframe or something? Can someone tell me what I am missing? TIA!

My code is:

```
val df = z.get("wds")                           
df.getClass.getSimpleName
df.select(explode($"filtered").as("value")).groupBy("value").count.show
```

This gives the folowwing (edited) output:

```
 df: Object = [racist: boolean, contributors: 
string, coordinates: string, ...n: Int = 20
    res35: String = DataFrame
    <console>:62: error: value select is not a member of Object
                  df.select(explode($"filtered").as("value")).groupBy("value").count.show
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was missing

```
.asInstanceOf[DataFrame]
```

i.e.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
val df = z.get("wds").asInstanceOf[DataFrame]
```